# How do I resolve a rivalry with my wife?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

How do I resolve a rivalry with a character, or specifically in this case, my character's wife? I bagged my character a duchess as a wife (and not matrilineal) which means that the first kid produced will be heir to that duchy - and since I have elective, I can easily set him up as my heir as well. Good, right?

Except that now they're rivals, the character's getting old and I don't have the time to resolve this in a lengthy manner. Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to resolve a rivalry is to wait for an event to fire. But, also as far as I know, rivalry with your wife does not affect the chances of having children. If you are not having any it's more likely to be due to fertility. If you get a chance to become lustful or a hedonist, it can do wonders. Beyond that, it's a dice roll. You have a nonzero chance of peaceful expansion.